# vim insert mode dollar sign is slow

Tags: vim

I'm new to vim. I use predefined [.vimrc](https://github.com/amix/vimrc) and have some small problems with it. Whenever I type the $ sign in insert mode, the insertion stops for a moment, and if I would type, for example, 1 afterwards two brackets () will be inserted. I don't know which of the plugins causes this behavior but I would like to disable it.

Can someone help me?

Comment: I would recommend *not* using a canned .vimrc until you are familiar with Vim's default configuration. The `extended.vim` you linked to has [all sorts of key sequences starting with `$`](https://github.com/amix/vimrc/blob/master/vimrcs/extended.vim#L80) mapped to commands you may or may not care about. Every time you type `$`, `vim` is waiting to see if the next character you type is part of one of those pre-defined commands.

Comment: You can comment out the offending `*map` commands, but I would recommend simply browsing through such files for ideas and copying the ones you like to your own `.vimrc`.

Comment: I guess I go with my own .vimrc then. Thank you :)

Comment: Going with your own .vimrc is the way to go. YouTube has some videos where experienced vim users cover some ideas in their .vimrc's. Also, search for 'vimrc' on github. Many power users share theirs, and many are heavily commented. Good luck and welcome to vim. It will grow on you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation for this framework spells out this mapping on its main page:

```
inoremap $1 ()<esc>I
```

This mapping and related ones are specified in the extended vimrc file starting on line 82: https://github.com/amix/vimrc/blob/master/vimrcs/extended.vim

So, just delete those mappings in your copy of that file.

Note: I don't know anything about this project, nor have I tested this out. I'm just assuming this will work after quickly reviewing the project with the link you provided.